# Filter a larger DataFrame using date ranges and column values from a smaller one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a larger `DataFrame`, **`df1`**, that looks like this:

```
                         Data
PatId  EntryDate  Id                                        
725    2005-01-03 1422   X
       2005-01-04 1563   X
       2005-01-05 1355   X
       2005-01-06 118    X
       2005-01-09 1400   X
...                                                       
117785 2004-12-31 799998 X
       2005-01-03 796833 X
       2005-01-05 798728 X
       2005-01-08 798545 X 
       2005-01-11 797632 X
```

And a smaller `DataFrame`, **`df2`** that looks like this:

```
                         PatId
EntryDate  ExitDate          
2005-01-15 2005-04-15   22407
2005-01-30 2005-04-30   95938
2005-02-07 2005-05-07  116812
2005-02-18 2005-05-18   12163
2005-02-21 2005-05-21   22908
```

**I'd like an elegant way to filter `df1` to only include the rows for each `PatId` that lie between the `EntryDate` and `ExitDate` indexes in `df2`.**

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I've managed to filter the `DataFrame` based on date alone using `pd.concat` and slicing via the `EntryDate` and `ExitDate`, but I'm not sure how to also filter it by each date range's corresponding `PatId`.

Comment: @spacemud Id and PatId are same? can you show the output please?

Comment: @YOLO No - `Id` is a unique identifier for each row from when this data was read from CSV. `PatId` is short for patient ID, and a single patient might have multiple records relating to them. I updated my question to make things a bit clearer. What do you mean by 'show the output'?

Comment: Are these `dataframes` excessively large? There's a rather simple and short way to accomplish this that isn't very memory efficient, but if that's not a concern, it's likely your best best.

Comment: About 800000 rows in `df1` but it has potential to get much bigger. I'd be interested in seeing your solution in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge both of the DataFrames together on just `PatId` which will bring the entry and exit dates to df1 and then you just need to use datetime comparisons to filter it down. I've also reset the indexing you had and got rid of the helper columns in the final display, but do what you want.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PatId': [725, 725, 725, 725, 117785, 117785],
                   'EntryDate': ['2005-01-03', '2005-01-04', '2005-01-05', '2005-01-06',
                                '2004-12-31', '2005-01-03'],
                   'Id': [1422, 1563, 1355, 118, 7999998, 796833],
                   'Data': ['X','X','X','X','X','X']})
df1['EntryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.EntryDate)
df1.set_index(['PatId', 'EntryDate', 'Id'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PatId': [725, 117785],
                   'EntryDate': ['2005-01-04', '2005-01-02'],
                   'ExitDate': ['2005-01-05', '2006-01-18']})
df2['EntryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.EntryDate)
df2['ExitDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.ExitDate)
df2.set_index(['EntryDate', 'ExitDate'])
```

And this is the actual code:

```
df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on='PatId', how='left', suffixes=['','_1'])

(df[(df.EntryDate >= df['EntryDate_1']) & (df.EntryDate <= df.ExitDate)]
    .drop(columns=['EntryDate_1', 'ExitDate'])
    .set_index(['PatId', 'EntryDate', 'Id']))

                         Data
PatId  EntryDate  Id         
725    2005-01-04 1563      X
       2005-01-05 1355      X
117785 2005-01-03 796833    X
```